# Python 3 + Click: CLI arguments get butchered when calling one command from another

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using Python 3.9 and Click to build a small command line interface utility, but I am getting strange errors, specifically when I attempt to call one function decorated as a `@click.command()` from another function that is also decorated the same way.

I have distilled my program down to the bare minimum to explain what I mean.

This is my program

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.argument('id')
def outer(id):
    print('outer id',id,type(id))
    inner(id)  # run inner() from within outer(), pass argument unchanged

@click.command()       # *
@click.argument('id')  # *
def inner(id):
    print('inner id',id,type(id))

cli.add_command(outer)
cli.add_command(inner)  # *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

This is the CLI result when I run my script using both the `inner` and `outer` commands:

```
% python3 test.py inner 123
inner id 123 <class 'str'>
% python3 test.py outer 123
outer id 123 <class 'str'>
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] ID
Try 'test.py --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (2 3)
%
```

Interestingly, it works when I use a single character argument:

```
% python3 test.py outer 1
outer id 1 <class 'str'>
inner id 1 <class 'str'>
%
```

If I comment out the three lines marked with `# *`, running the `outer` command behaves as expected, passing on the `id` argument to `inner()` without changes or issues, no matter the length of the argument:

```
% python3 test.py outer 123
outer id 123 <class 'str'>
inner id 123 <class 'str'>
%
```

Clearly, the decorators are somehow messing with the arguments. Can anybody explain *why* this is, and *how* I can achieve the desired behavior of passing on the arguments unchanged? Maybe I am missing something super obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [context operations](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/advanced/#invoking-other-commands) to invoke other commands

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.argument('id')
@click.pass_context
def outer(ctx, id):
    print('outer id',id,type(id))
    ctx.forward(inner)  # run inner(), pass argument unchanged
    ctx.invoke(inner, id=id+1) # run inner(), pass modified argument

@click.command()       # *
@click.argument('id')  # *
def inner(id):
    print('inner id',id,type(id))

cli.add_command(outer)
cli.add_command(inner)  # *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Comment: Actually, there's a simpler way: See https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/advanced/#invoking-other-commands